# Add pagination to custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress

i would like to know how to add pagination to recent custom posts? I´m very new to wordpress but i´m learning every day.

With this code i would like to show 10x of the latest posts and add a pagination below where i can show next 10x posts and also choose specific page 1-10. Right now i just list all my recent posts with this code. Thank you so much in advance!

```html
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<table>
<?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type' => array( 'books', 'movies' ), ));
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        echo '<tr><td>' . $recent["post_date"] . '</td><td>' . $recent["post_type"] . '</td><td><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </td></tr> ';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to functions.php

```
function content_nav() {

if( is_singular() )
    return;

global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

/** Previous Post Link */
if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Add following in style.css

```
/*numeric navigation starts*/
.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
    background-color: #6FB7E9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px;
    padding: 0.75rem;
}

.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a {
    background-color: #3C8DC5;
}
/*numeric navigation finish*/
```

And add following, if you want to add navgation in different page templates such as archive.php,category.php and its mandatory in index.php if you want pagination on your index page.

```
<?php content_nav(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you call `<?php content_nav(); ?>` on your index.php?? Its working great on mine and it should work on your too without any doubt.